# Change two dropdowns select option depend on datepicker select day and month

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker-ui. I get the date that user choose and put that month in a dropdown option like this.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
   //Below line will set format for date "Month year" .Note This format is custom,according to the drop down value
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "MM yy" );
   //On change of Date from date picker, this will set value in select dropdown
   $('#datepicker').change(function(){
   $('#name_id').val($('#datepicker').val());
        });
  } );
  
 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Calendar: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>
 

<div class="input-group col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 search">
      <label class="bd-form-label" style="float: left;width: 100%;">Dates</label>
         <select name="name" id="name_id" style="width: 80%;float: left;">
            <option value="">Any Month</option>
            <option value="October 2017">October 2017</option>
            <option value="November 2017">November 2017</option>
            <option value="December 2017">December 2017</option>
            <option value="January 2018">January 2018</option>
         </select>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

It is working for month and year. Is it possible to add another select option like this :

```
<select name="name" id="name_id_day" style="width: 80%;float: left;">
   <option value="">Any Day</option>
   <option value="01">01</option>
   <option value="02">02</option>
   <option value="03">03</option>
   <option value="04">04</option>
</select>
```

Next to date and change the day like i am doing with the month/year?

I tried by changing the js script from :

```
$( function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
  //Below line will set format for date "Month year" .Note This format is custom,according to the drop down value
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "MM yy" );
  //On change of Date from date picker, this will set value in select dropdown
  $('#datepicker').change(function(){
        $('#name_id').val($('#datepicker').val());
    });
} );
```

To:

```
$( function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
  //Below line will set format for date "Month year" .Note This format is custom,according to the drop down value
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "D MM yy" );
  //On change of Date from date picker, this will set value in select dropdown
  $('#datepicker').change(function(){
        $('#name_id').val($('#datepicker').val());
    });
} );
```

By adding on dateFormat the day `D MM YY` but after that is not  working at all.

Any feedback?

Comment: is it bootstrap datepicker?

Comment: Is a jquery-ui datepicker in a bootstrap theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var monthyearData = "";
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd MM YY',
    yearRange: '2017:2020'
  });

  $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "d MM yy");
  $('#datepicker').change(function() {
    monthyearData = $('#datepicker').val().split(" ");
    $('#cruise_date').val(monthyearData[1] + " " + monthyearData[2]);
    $('#cruise_date_1').val(monthyearData[0]);
  });
});


</script>
```

Comment: This not gonna help me.. I already tried dd-mm-yy and  dd MM YY and is not working.. Whats the difference if I use dd-mm-yy just gonna change the format and - nothing else.

Comment: you can use like this $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "d MM yy" );

Comment: If you read my question I already did it.. I am saying that i change that from to and is not even working

Comment: So basically maybe I am not much clear. I need to take the value from datepicker input. and take the day in one dropdown and the rest in the other

Comment: Yes I know that, I am just telling i tried all of this just in case

Comment: This is not my problem. I can not pass the date value in two dropdown

Comment: i think you have to create 1 to 31 drop down manually and create second drop down same month and year

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157270/discussion-between-maria-and-jinesh).